# Validation Error in USCIS Website - While checking H1B Status

Tags: h1-visa

I am unable to track my process and worried about my case status. Anyone received approval from them?. How to resolve this issue.Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I called them. After a long wait, the call got connected and the representative informed me that beneficiary is not allowed to know the status through them and  he will reveal only to the employer. My employer said that, it is not a good idea to call and ask about the status, there is nothing to worry about this and it might be a technical issue. I am hoping the same !! There is nothing we can do than waiting :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried phoning USCIS at 800-375-5283?

The phone agents have  access to more detailed records than the online system does.